# Using NSStepper to set ceiling value instead of incrementing value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am using a `NSStepper` along with a `NSTextField`. The user can either set the value using the text field or can use the NSStepper to change the value. I will quote my question using the example below:
Suppose the current value of my stepper is 4 and increment value of the stepper is 2:
[image]

After I click the UP arrow on the NSStepper the value becomes:
[image]

Now Suppose the current value would have been 4.5 i.e.:
[image]

After using the UP arrow the value becomes:
[image]

What I require is that when the current value is 4.5, after using the UP arrow, the value becomes **6** instead of 6.5

Any ideas to accomplish this are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> What I require is that when the current value is 4.5, after using the
>   UP arrow, the value becomes 6 instead of 6.5

Hard to tell exactly what you are asking but taking a guess: it sounds like you want to remove the decimal part of the number and increment by your defined step amount (2). You can do this through the `floor()` function. [See here for other Objective-C math functions](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/objective-c-math-functions/)

> double floor ( double ) - removes the decimal part of the argument

```
NSLog(@"res: %.f", floor(3.000000000001)); 
//result 3 
NSLog(@"res:%.f", floor(3.9999999));
//result 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, this code will give you the next even number (up or down depending on which arrow you click), but still allow you to enter non-integer numbers in the text filed. tf and stepper are IBOutlets and num is a property (a float) that keeps track of the value of the stepper before you click an arrow so you can compare with the new number to see if the up or down arrow was clicked.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.num = 0;
    self.tf.intValue = 0; //the stepper is set to 0 in IB
}


-(IBAction)textFieldDidChange:(id)sender {
    self.num = self.stepper.floatValue = [sender floatValue];
}


-(IBAction)stepperDidChange:(id)sender {
    if (self.num < self.stepper.floatValue) { //determines whether the up or down arrow was clicked
        self.num = self.stepper.intValue = self.tf.intValue = [self nextLargerEven:self.num];
    }else{
        self.num = self.stepper.intValue = self.tf.intValue =[self nextSmallerEven:self.num];
    }
}

-(int)nextLargerEven:(float) previousValue {
    if ((int)previousValue % 2 == 0) {
        return (int)previousValue + 2;
    }else
        return (int)previousValue + 1;
}


-(int)nextSmallerEven:(float) previousValue {
    if ((int)previousValue % 2 == 0) {
        if ((int)previousValue == previousValue) {
            return (int)previousValue - 2;
        }else{
            return (int)previousValue;
        }
    }else
        return (int)previousValue - 1; 
}
```

Comment: & @skinnyTod Sorry for the unclear question. I have already achieved sync b/w the textfield and stepper. Question is:
 If the `minvalue = 0` and `maxValue = 100 and `increment = 2`,then the possible values for stepper are:
 0,2,4,6,....96,98,100.
 But if the user sets the value of `textField = 0.5` , the value of the stepper also becomes 0.5 ( _because text field and stepper are in sync_ ) so on clicking the stepper the values which will be displayed are:
 0.5, 2.5, 4.5,....., 96.5 , 88.5 
This is the behaviour I want to suppress and I want  values to become 
0.5, 2, 4, ......

Comment: @etheory, I don't see how this can work the way I think you want it to. One thing you could do is when you sync the stepper to the text field, calculate the next lower even number, so if the user enters 3.5, you would set the stepper to 2.  This would work if the user then clicks the up arrow to give you 4 (which is what I think you want) but if he clicks the down arrow you will get 0, which I'm presuming is not what you want -- there's no way to do this without reading the users mind.  Is there a reason you don't want to force the user to enter even integers into the text field?

Comment: Actually I need both kind of functionalities, the standard one and the one I mentioned in the comment above as well. In my application, I need to use the standard implementation at some places and the non-standard one at others. Is there any way we can extend NSSlider and override something to achieve this?

Comment: What I meant to say in my last comment was there is no easy way to do this using bindings or something like takeDoubleValueFrom, but it can be done.  See my edited answer.